# Angular ng-if directive continuously consumes more memory when data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with an Angular app I've been working. It displays rows of data and uses ng-if directives in each column to control prefixes and other descriptive text or images.

It works great, except that memory usage continues to grow and fairly fast depending on how much data I'm displaying and how quickly it changes.

I've written a plunk that demonstrates the issue. I'm using the [timeline memory view](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling) in Chrome dev tools to view memory usage. If you take out the ng-if directives, memory will return to normal after each GC.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wcl9eJWy1AXqcNr8rpf1

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="RepoCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <th>Repo</th>
                    <th>Owner</th>
                    <th>Git URL</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
                    <td>
                        <p ng-if="repo.name">{{ repo.name }}</p>
                    <td>
                        <p ng-if="repo.owner.login">{{ repo.owner.login }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p ng-if="repo.git_url">{{ repo.git_url }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p ng-if="repo.description">{{ repo.description }}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngResource']);

    app.factory('RepoFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        console.log('updated data');
        return $resource(':user.json', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }]);

    app.controller("RepoCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'RepoFactory', function ($scope, $http, $interval, RepoFactory) {
        function poll() {
            if (typeof $scope.last === 'undefined') {
                $scope.last = 'vye';
                console.log('no previous query, using vye')
            } else if ($scope.last == 'vye') {
                $scope.last = 'angular';
                console.log('got repos for vye last time, using angular')
            } else if ($scope.last == 'angular') {
                $scope.last = 'vye';
                console.log('got repos for angular last time, using vye')
            }
            RepoFactory.query({user: $scope.last}, function(data){
                $scope.repos = data;
            });
        }

        var promise = $interval(poll, 5000);

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            if (angular.isDefined(promise)) {
                $interval.cancel(promise);
                promise = undefined;
            }
        });
    }]);

</script>
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior due to an oversight on my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with AngularJS that has been fixed in the most recent release (1.3.0-beta.14).

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8105